# How to attach a current Word document to a new Sharepoint 2013 list item

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-office, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am develop a **word addin**. And i need create a new item in a existing Sharepoint list, with the current document like attachment.

```
var attInfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
attInfo.FileName = "Test";
attInfo.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(**here my current document**));
ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
oListItem["Title"] = "My New Item!";    
oListItem.AttachmentFiles.Add(attInfo);
```

How i put my current document there. Appreciate your help. Regards

Answer (score 0):

After saving the document, ** ActiveDocument ** Path property, has the full path

```
 attInfo.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(**Globals.ThisAddIn.ActiveDocument.FullName**));
```